# Apply different texture to overlayed canvas with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, textures

I need to implement a way to apply different texture to quite complicated nested canvas. Consider for example this image:

[Car](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMqNI.png)

[image]

I want to let the user to choose a fabric for the door and another for the rest of the body with different features such as scale, rotation angle and transparency.

Is there a js library that can help or pure javascript (maybe with HTML5) is enough?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, you can texturize your car using only native html5 canvas.**

[image]

No libraries are necessary because your tasks are simple and canvas has built-in methods for all the things you're wanting to do.

Start by creating an image for each part of your car. Each part-image will be opaque where you want the texture applied and transparent where you don't want the texture applied.

[image]

To apply a texture to any part, first draw the part on a second in-memory canvas. Then draw your texture on top of the second canvas. You can constrain your texture to only fill within the desired part using the `source-atop` compositing mode.

You can scale & rotate the texture using `context.scale` & `context.rotate`.

You can control the transparency of the texture using `context.globalAlpha`.

When you have your part textured as desired, just draw the in-memory (part) canvas to the main canvas.

**Here is example code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

var c=document.createElement('canvas');
var cctx=c.getContext('2d');
var cw,ch;

var car=new Image();
car.onload=start;
car.src='https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/carForTexturing.png';
var door=new Image();
door.onload=start;
door.src='https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/doorForTexturing.png';
var texture1=new Image();
texture1.onload=start;
texture1.src='https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/texture1.png';
var imgCount=3;
function start(){
  if(--imgCount>0){return;}

  cw=canvas.width=c.width=car.width;
  ch=canvas.height=c.height=car.height;

  ctx.drawImage(car,0,0);

  texturize(door, texture1, 0.50, Math.PI/4, 0.30);

  ctx.drawImage(c,0,0);
}

function texturize(carpartImage,texture,scale,rotation,opacity){
  cctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  cctx.drawImage(carpartImage,0,0);
  cctx.save();
  cctx.translate(cw/2,ch/2);
  cctx.rotate(rotation);
  cctx.globalAlpha=opacity;
  cctx.globalCompositeOperation='source-atop';
  cctx.drawImage(texture,-texture.width/2,-texture.height/2)
  cctx.restore();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=842 height=596></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you @markE for your answer I'll try it ASAP! That goes in the direction I wanted to try.